# Show that $f:= \frac{1 - 2x}{x^2 - 1}$ is monotonically increasing in the open interval $(-1, 1)$

Tags: calculus

Show that $f:= \frac{1 - 2x}{x^2 - 1}$ is monotonically increasing in the open interval $(-1, 1)$

To show a function is monotonically increasing, I started by saying that:

> A function $f$ is monotonically increasing in an interval $(a, b)$ if for all $x, y \in (a, b)$, with $x$ < $y$, we have that $f(x) \leq f(y)$.

So I started by tryin to show:

> Let $x$, $y$ be arbitrary fixed numbers in $(-1, 1)$, with $x < y$, we want to show that $f(x) \leq f(y)$:
>   $$f(x) = \frac{1 - 2x}{x^2 - 1} \leq \frac{1 - 2y}{y^2 - 1} = f(y)$$
>   We multiply the left side by $\frac{y^2 - 1}{y^2 - 1}$, which is positive because $y^2$ is always less than $1$, so we don't need to change the sign:
>   $$\frac{1 - 2x}{x^2 - 1}\cdot \frac{y^2 - 1}{y^2 - 1} \leq \frac{1 - 2y}{y^2 - 1}$$
>   We know multiply by $\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2 - 1}$ the right side:
>   $$\frac{1 - 2x}{x^2 - 1}\cdot \frac{y^2 - 1}{y^2 - 1} \leq \frac{1 - 2y}{y^2 - 1} \cdot \frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2 - 1}$$
>   So we can simplify:
>   $$(1 - 2x)\cdot (y^2 - 1) \leq (1 - 2y) \cdot (x^2 - 1)$$

Now, how do we proceed? Is this correct?

Comment: Just to be sure, you haven't seen derivatives yet ?

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution:
$$ f(x)=\frac{1-2x}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{x+1}\right)\tag{1}$$
and both $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{-1}{x+1}$ are increasing over $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

A differentiable function in some interval is monotonically aascending if its derivative is *positive*:

$$f'(x)=\frac{-2(x^2-1)-2x(1-2x)}{(x^2-1)^2}=\frac{-2x^2+2-2x+4x^2}{(x^2-1)^2}=$$

$$=2\frac{x^2-x+1}{(x^2-1)^2}$$

Now just prove the above indeed is positive **for all** $\;x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,1\}\;$ , in particular in $\;(-1,1)\;$ .

**Another way:** Suppose $\;x<y\;$ , then ( observe that $\;t^2-1<0\;$ for $\;t\in(-1,1)\;$ )

$$f(x)<f(y)\iff\frac{1-2x}{x^2-1}<\frac{1-2y}{y^2-1}\iff y^2-1-2xy^2+2x>x^2-1-2x^2y+2y$$

$$\iff(y-x)\left[(y+x)-2xy-2\right]>0$$

Since $\;y-x>0\;$ , it is enough to show the other factor is positive: this part is for you.

Comment: Nothing: I was misled by the square denominator ...I'll try to correct this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without derivatives:

Note that we can write for $|x|<1$

$$f(x)=\frac{1-2x}{x^2-1}= \frac{-1/2}{x-1}+ \frac{-3/2}{x+1}$$

If we take $y>x$, then we have

$$f(y)-f(x) =\frac{y-x}{2(x-1)(y-1)}+\frac{3(y-x)}{2(x+1)(y+1)}>0$$

for all $-1<x<y<1$